# How do I reattach a door handle lever with a concealed screw

Tags: doors

A door handle to one of the rooms in my apartment has come loose. I cannot find an exact match online but it is similar in construction to [this door handle](http://www.handles4homes.co.uk/eurospec-zin116-atalaya-door-handle-on-rose/).

The issue is that the lever part has come loose from the base. The mechanism itself is not loose from the door.

I cannot work out how to reattach the lever and I am wary of causing further damage by disassembling too much more. I cannot find any kind of manual or guide for this type of handle, but that may be due to not knowing the right terminology for my search. Here is how it looks: [image] There is a central screw-like thing that should connect the lever to the handle - it wobbles and rotates freely but does not come out of the base. I can put the lever in place but not rotate it in-place without moving the whole handle.

There is a grub screw underneath but I'm not sure which part of the handle it is meant to secure:[image]. Do I take apart the whole thing? Any advice is much appreciated.

It should look like this when assembled: [image]

Comment: Looking at the [help here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I am not confident that this is on-topic ("contractors and (serious) DIY'ers") so please feel free to direct this elsewhere

Comment: The set screw is typically holding on the entire handle. Try removing the other side since you'll have more of a handle to jiggle it off. Door knobs with a locking mechanisms will only be able to be removed from the non-locking side so a set screw may be holding a shaft connecting the two knobs as well.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the removal of the set screw (which you called the grub screw) will allow the post piece of the door knob to be removed from the door. A good pull may be required to remove it.

You should look at the door handle on the opposite side to see if it also has a similar set screw. If it does not have any visible means of removal then the knob from the opposite side will pull from the door extracting a central shaft which is extending into the post that you see on this side. The set screw in this case is holding the handles in place from both sides.

Once you get the post off the near side reattaching your knob lever should be as easy as accessing the head of the central screw from the inside of the post piece. The central screw head may use a normal screw driver or may be a six sided hex similar to the set screw head.